# Schema first and simple membership?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

I’m trying to build database using schema first (EF5) and add it simple membership as well.

After ”drawing” my schema  I have add user profile table (UserId&UserName) remove the

Filter: InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute, remove all of this ..

```
//public class UsersContext : DbContext
//{
//    public UsersContext()
//        : base("DefaultConnection")
//    {
//    }

//    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

//}

//[Table("UserProfile")]
//public class UserProfile
//{
//    [Key]
//    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
//    public int UserId { get; set; }
//    public string UserName { get; set; }
//}
```

In the generated class (by schema first) I have tried to add manually

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

to my UserProfile class

I have also register in my AppStart  :

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Model1Container", "UserProfile",
    "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

But on debug I’m getting this error :

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed

WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Model1Container", "UserProfile",
```

Is there a good practice how to do it ?

Is it possible using schema first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice , you have removed following part which had the connection name.

```
public UsersContext()
//        : base("DefaultConnection")
//    {
//    }
```

Just add that in your context class. And Yes , you can do it using Code first Approach and I think it is a lot easier than what your are doing now..

Comment: Thanks.i think I will use the Code first Approach.